# What default mechanisms are in place in ASP.net for user login?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I veguely remember that there was a login/logout control in my ASP.net class, but I don't know what options there are for managing user logins, the only one I'm aware of is the Windows Authentication mechanism.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: There is a lot to it so may be you can explain "managing use logins" specifically. Because it could be just authenticating user, creating/deleting user or authorization specific...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're talking about ASP.NET Forms Authentication. You can read [more about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a video tutorial on the ASP.NET Login controls:

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/login-controls

You'll probably want to take a look at Forms Authentication - you can use both Windows and Forms authentication with an ASP.NET Web application.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx